# AlertDialog = new AlertDialog.builder(this) gets typecast error

Tags: android, dialog

When I create AlertDialog class object and then by new AlertDialog.builder(this) than it gives me following error shown in screen shot below, If I use builder object than cancel() function does not work and give me force close error in emulator

[image: When I create AlertDialog class object and then by new AlertDialog.builder(this) than it gives me following error shown in screen shot below, If I use builder object than cancel() function does not work and give me force close error in emulator]

Answer (score 4):

Please change,

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

Because an `AlertDialog` ist **not** an `AlertDialog.Builder()`. You can find a complete example for creating an `AlertDialog` below:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
alertDialog.setTitle("Alert 1");  
alertDialog.setMessage("This is an alert");  
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
        return;  
    } 
});  

AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

the **AlertDialog** exist in two class: `android.app.AlertDialog, android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`. Please make sure that you use the same **AlertDialog** in your class.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **AlertDialog** instead of **AlertDialog.Builder**. that error(i.e., mainContentScreen:Cannot convert from AlertDialog.Builder to AlertDialog) clearly showing that where you did the mistake. Please read the error carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

and refer this link
  : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

Below should work

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```